# Can't display from async function result

Tags: vue.js, fetch

I need to display in my html variable: `{my_dates}`. The problem that I can't get it work with `fetch` but can do with old ajax request.

not working code:

```
   created: function(){
        //this.getTableData()

        url = 'http://dlang.ru/test'

        async function fetchAsync () {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          return await response.json();
        }

        this.my_dates = fetchAsync();

    }
```

Working code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://dlang.ru/test",
    success: function (data) {
         Vue.set(app, "my_dates", data);
         app.show = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your problem is that you didn't declare `created` as async. Check the answer for more details.

Comment: @dfsq `created` should not be declared as `async`, that could/would have unintended side-effects for `vue`

Comment: @Derek That's the only way if OP wants to use `fetchAsync` like this `this.my_dates = fetchAsync();`

Comment: @dfsq that is not the only way, see Sergii's answer for one example

Comment: @Derek Well additional wrapper: not the same. But I really doubt that "*would have unintended side-effects for vue*" is true. It should not matter really, since `created` will be called anyway, doesn't matter that it returns Promise. Well this is my understanding, I might be wrong.

Comment: `created: async function()` work only if I add this.my_dates = await fetchAsync();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to assign result of `fetchAsync()` to `this.my_dates` then entire `created` hook method needs to be declared as `async`.

Then you also need `await` in front of `fetchAsync` call:

```javascript
created: async function () {
  const url = 'http://dlang.ru/test';

  async function fetchAsync() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.json();
  }

  this.my_dates = await fetchAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 created: function(){
    //this.getTableData()

    url = 'http://dlang.ru/test'

    async function fetchAsync () {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      Vue.set(app, "my_dates", data);
      app.show = true;
    }

    fetchAsync();

}
```

Comment: Basically you assign promise to `this.my_dates` and not the actual result. That is why you need to assign "my_dates" property after you have promise result, as in example with jquery you provided.

Comment: Could you please update the issue with your component code? As it is not clear why it does not work.